# How to create fyne splash screen. I don't find any widget in fyne GUI toolkit

Tags: user-interface, go

I have not found any widget to create splash screen using fyne GUI toolkit. I have found one method for splashscreen in desktop driver interface but cannot figured it out how to use it?

Could anyone please make me understand this, how can I create splashscreen in fyne GUI?

Answer (score 3):

The desktop driver is the place to go, the trick is that you need to check if the current driver is for a desktop, after then you can call it.

You can see this in action inside the [fyne_demo source code](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/a0665a73f46213ce9d9353858039132a09e15359/cmd/fyne_demo/screens/window.go#L205):

The code is basically:

```golang
    if drv, ok := fyne.CurrentApp().Driver().(desktop.Driver); ok {
        w := drv.CreateSplashWindow()
        w.SetContent(widget.NewLabel("Hello World"))
        w.Show()
    }
```