# How to hide taskbar in fyne golang?

Tags: go, fyne

I need to hide taskbar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ECHT.png),but how?
I did not find anything in the documentation and on the Internet too.
I hope that one of you is engaged in golang, and will be able to answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s the window border, not the task bar. It is around all desktop Fyne windows except a splash window.
The answer here will help [How to create fyne splash screen. I don't find any widget in fyne GUI toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62383370/how-to-create-fyne-splash-screen-i-dont-find-any-widget-in-fyne-gui-toolkit).